# Adding custom psuedo CSS to class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Bit of a tricky situation here, I have the following class:

```
<li><a href="test.html" class="hvr-overline-from-left">Test</a></li>
```

This is the CSS for it:

```
.hvr-overline-from-left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hvr-overline-from-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  background: #47953F;
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

This is what should change when scrolling down:

```
.hvr-overline-from-leftsmall:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  top: 15%;
  background: #47953F;
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var line = $('.hvr-overline-from-left:before');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 13.35) {
            line.addClass("hvr-overline-from-leftsmall:before");
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() >= 0) {
            line.removeClass("hvr-overline-from-leftsmall:before");
        }
    });
});
```

This does not work ofcourse, my question is how I can make this work properly? I do not know what class I should call to change psuedo elements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `("hvr-overline-from-leftsmall:before")` remove `:before` because jQuery not select pseudo elements

Answer (score 1):

You just add the *class* `hvr-overline-from-leftsmall`, without the `:before` selector; e.g.:

```
line.addClass("hvr-overline-from-leftsmall");
// No :before here -----------------------^
```

(And of course the same for `removeClass` later.)

Provided that's defined after the `hvr-overline-from-left` class's rules, it will take precedence in any style conflicts.

The `:before` is part of the rule selector, not the class.

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid now, sometimes you have to remove things to make things work

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the class without the pseudo-element:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 13.35) {
    line.addClass("hvr-overline-from-leftsmall");
} else if($(this).scrollTop() >= 0) {
    line.removeClass("hvr-overline-from-leftsmall");
}
```

The `::before` will come in automatically when you change the class, as it'll override your `hvr-overline-from-left` rules.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to rewrite all the styles for this.
Change you CSS like this:

```
.hvr-overline-from-left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hvr-overline-from-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  background: #47953F;
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-overline-from-left.small:before {
  top: 15%;
}
```

and then in your script just add/remove the `small` class:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 13.35) {
    line.addClass("small");
} else if($(this).scrollTop() >= 0) {
    line.removeClass("small");
}
```